# What are the Scriptural Recitals During Shukravara Chandramaulishwara Puja?

Tags: shiva, adi-shankaracharya, puja

What are Parayanams(Scriptural Recitals) of Chandramaulishwara Puja held every Friday at Shringeri Sharada Peetham? Apart from Rudra Prashna and Durga Suktam?

Comment: Chandramouliswara puja happens every day. What specific Friday puja are you referring to ?

Comment: @moonstar I watch Chandramaulishwara Puja Coverage of Shringeri which airs only on Friday, But wat r d respective Scriptural Recitals